# Having trouble reading this notation

Tags: notation

I'm having trouble reading and understanding this mathematical notation about conformal meshes:

$$\bar{\Omega} = \cup_{K\in T_{h}}K.$$

$\Omega$ is a domain, and $K$ is an element of $T_h$. $T_h$ is a conformal mesh of domain $\Omega$.

One, is this reading correct: $\Omega$ is the finite sequence elements, $K$, in $T_h$ in the collection $K$.

Two, what does this mean?

Comment: It means that the elements of $\bar\Omega$ are the elements of the sets $K$ that are elements of $T_h$. (I can't help beyond that definition, because I don't know numerical analysis well enough. I looked at this question only because it claimed, incorrectly, to be about model theory.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass thanks for pointing that out. I removed the model theory tag.